# vb.NET You are not allowed to perform an operation across different threads

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, word-cloud

I am running code to read text from pdf files and than create a `WordCloud`. To inform the user the process is on going I add a `BackgroundWorker` to my form that shows an `image` saying Loading. I get an error for operating across different threads.

```
Private Sub ButtonCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCreate.Click

        bTextEmpty = False
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        ResultPictureBox.Image = Nothing

        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            For Each Item As Object In ListBox1.SelectedItems
                Dim ItemSelected = CType(Item("Path"), String)
                Dim myTempFile As Boolean = File.Exists(ItemSelected + "\Words.txt")
                If myTempFile = False Then
                    'when we load the form we first call the code to count words in all files in a directory
                    'lets check if the folder exists
                    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(ItemSelected)) Then
                        Dim unused = MsgBox("The archive " + ItemSelected.Substring(ItemSelected.Length - 5, Length) + " was not found",, Title)
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        Call CreateWordList(ItemSelected)
                    End If
                End If
                'if the words file is empty we cant create a cloud so exit the sub
                If bTextEmpty = True Then Exit Sub
                'then we fill the wordcloud and Listview from the created textfile
                Call CreateMyCloud(ItemSelected + "\Words.txt")
            Next
        Else
            Dim unused = MsgBox("You have to choose an Archive to create the Word Cloud",, Title)
        End If
        Size = New Drawing.Size(1400, 800)

    End Sub
```

I put above code in a Private Sub and called it from my `BackgroundWorker`. The error occured at this line: `If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then`

After trying the suggested code I get the same error again:

```
Public Sub CreateMyCloud(ByVal sourcePDF As String)

        Dim WordsFreqList As New List(Of WordsFrequencies)
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(sourcePDF)
            Dim splitText As String() = line.Split(","c)
            If splitText IsNot Nothing AndAlso splitText.Length = 2 Then
                Dim wordFrq As New WordsFrequencies
                Dim freq As Integer
                wordFrq.Word = splitText(0)
                wordFrq.Frequency = If(Integer.TryParse(splitText(1), freq), freq, 0)
                WordsFreqList.Add(wordFrq)
            End If
        Next
        If WordsFreqList.Count > 0 Then
            ' Order the list based on the Frequency
            WordsFreqList = WordsFreqList.OrderByDescending(Function(w) w.Frequency).ToList
            ' Add the sorted items to the listview
            WordsFreqList.ForEach(Sub(wf)
                            error ->  ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {wf.Word, wf.Frequency.ToString}, 0))
                                  End Sub)
        End If

        Dim wc As WordCloudGen = New WordCloudGen(600, 400)
        Dim i As Image = wc.Draw(WordsFreqList.Select(Function(wf) wf.Word).ToList, WordsFreqList.Select(Function(wf) wf.Frequency).ToList)
        ResultPictureBox.Image = i


    End Sub
```

Comment: Move the body of the code into another method.  If no item is selected then you simply don't start the worker.

Comment: In general, from the UI thread (the button click handler), you should collect the items to be worked on from your ListBox into a  `List(Of String)`, and then pass that to `RunWorkerAsync()`.  That can be retrieved in the `DoWork()` handler via the `DoWorkEventArgs` parameter, as in `e.Argument`.

Comment: When you want to update the UI, use the `ReportProgress()` method which will fire the `ProgressChanged()` event.  From that event it is safe to update the UI.  Similarly, when the BackgroundWorker is done, the `RunWorkerCompleted()` event will fire where you can do other updates to the UI.

Comment: @HansPassant could you show me how that would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should look something more like:

```
Private Sub ButtonCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCreate.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim data As New List(Of Object)
        For Each Item As Object In ListBox1.SelectedItems
            data.Add(Item)
        Next

        bTextEmpty = False
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        ResultPictureBox.Image = Nothing

        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(data)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You have to choose an Archive to create the Word Cloud",, Title)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim data As List(Of Object) = DirectCast(e.Argument, List(Of Object))
    For Each Item As Object In data
        Dim ItemSelected = CType(Item("Path"), String)
        Dim myTempFile As Boolean = File.Exists(ItemSelected + "\Words.txt")
        If myTempFile = False Then
            'when we load the form we first call the code to count words in all files in a directory
            'lets check if the folder exists
            If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(ItemSelected)) Then
                MessageBox.Show("The archive " + ItemSelected.Substring(ItemSelected.Length - 5, Length) + " was not found",, Title)
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Call CreateWordList(ItemSelected)
            End If
        End If
        'if the words file is empty we cant create a cloud so exit the sub
        If bTextEmpty = True Then Exit Sub
        'then we fill the wordcloud and Listview from the created textfile
        Call CreateMyCloud(ItemSelected + "\Words.txt")
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Size = New Drawing.Size(1400, 800)
End Sub
```

Comment: So its basically because I call the ListBox1 to see which items were selected?

Comment: Correct.  From within `DoWork()` you should not DIRECTLY access any UI controls.  It is possible to do, but you'd have to use `Invoke()` to make the call(s) thread safe.

Comment: I read that Invoke() is not really a safe solution.

Comment: `Invoke()` is perfectly safe when used correctly.  Most of the complaints you'll see are simply because it's an older way of doing things and that it "shouldn't" be mixed with other approaches such as with BackgroundWorker/Task.   It can technically be done, though.

Comment: I am goig to try your solution with the BackgroundWorker

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error in your second, edited post:

```
WordsFreqList.ForEach(Sub(wf)
                          ListView1.Invoke(Sub()
                                               ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {wf.Word, wf.Frequency.ToString}, 0))
                                           End Sub)
                      End Sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply access controls outside of the current thread. You first need to call the `Invoke` method on the target control and then pass a delegate containing the instructions intended to modify the control outside of the current thread. See this article on MSDN on how to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8